# How can we publish the web app with custom domain?

Tags: google-app-maker, custom-domain

Good Day!

We are building web apps with Google App Maker, How can we publish the web app with custom domain?

Thanks.

Heart

Comment: Such a feature does not exist but has been requested: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63382989 - If you only need an easy way to reach the app you can simply add a DNS rule to redirect to your app maker deployment URL.